# codeigniter 2: getting 404 error on default controller

Tags: php, routes, controller, codeigniter-2

I set default controller like this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "InterviewController";
```

So here is InterviewController's code

```
class InterviewController extends CI_Controller{
    private $em;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $commentsList = array();
        $commentsList['comments'] = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Comment')->findPage(1, 10, 'DESC', $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Interview')->getLast()[0]->getId());
        $lastInterviewsAnons = array();
        $lastInterviewsAnons['lastInterviewsAnons'] = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Interview')->getLast();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('navbar');
        $this->load->view('content', $lastInterviewsAnons);
        $this->load->view('addCommentPanel');
        $this->load->view('commentsList', $commentsList);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Everything works perfect in my local machine, but on server i get 404 error. I can access this controller only by typing full url like http://mydomain.com/index.php/InterviewController. Seems like instruction in routes file doesn't work. What can you advise?

Comment: Check your mod rewrite and your filename casing. Your filename should be lowercase and your URI too.

Comment: mod rewrite is enabled. I changed my filename to lowercase. Changed routing rule to $route['default_controller'] = "interviewcontroller";. Anyways i have 404

Comment: please post the content of .htaccess file related to this routing

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|robots\.txt|css|js|libraries/ckeditor|upload)
addDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: it is all i have in htaccess file

Comment: Your routing rule doesn't need to be lowercase, your URI and filename should. Like messi said a .htaccess would be informative right now.

Comment: everything works on local machine. that is strange. also everything works if i change default controller to those which is set as demo in codeigniter. i mean "welcome"

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded routes.php to server or does it still look for welcome.php ? :P recheck all naming conventions. If your mod rewrite isnt doing weird things it's in your configuration file or naming.\

Comment: i bring again welcome controller as in codeigniter demo. that works, but my controller doesn't. Can't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check your htaccess file for rewrite codes. If it is ok then try below steps.

1) Change Class name to

```
 class Interview extends CI_Controller
```

2) File name to  interview.php

3) And in routes.php $route['default_controller'] = "interview";

Comment: rewrite mod is ebanabled. i changed everything as you suggested. Goooood that doesn't work. Now it is the same like in codeigniter demo with it's welcome default controller, but welcome works, my controller - no

Comment: Also check interview.php file is in correct location (application/controllers folder) and all the view files from header to footer are in application/views folder. I know u might saved it in correct locations but just recheck..

Comment: Browser is caching url. So it loaded 404 again. Now everything is ok. Thanks, men